# Combo box winrt default style

Tags: combobox, windows-runtime

I have changed my default combo box style like this

```
<!--ComboBox Background and Border default Changed to Application Theme Style -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBorderThemeBrush" Color="#FFF3A716" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPressedBorderThemeBrush" Color="#FFF3A716" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF3A716" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeBrush" Color="#FFF3A716" />
<Thickness x:Key="ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness">1</Thickness>
<Thickness x:Key="ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeThickness">1</Thickness>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxHighlightedBorderThemeBrush" Color="#FFF3A716" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneHighContrastSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF3A716" />
```

But the problem is that when combo box has more than 5 elements it opens on whole screen and shows default styles not the one that i have override.

Combo boxes with 5 or less elements have these styles.

[image]

[image]

Edit: The above Images shows green colour, I want to change this green colour to orange.

[image]
 This is my combo box with less than 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the control template for ComboBox. You can fetch it by adding a ComboBox to a Page in "Blend for Visual Studio" and then right-click on the combobox and select "Edit Template"->"Edit a Copy". View source and you will find the complete style template for your ComboBox there.

You should get this:

```
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="ComboBoxGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="PointerOver" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneMidBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ComboBoxFlyoutListPlaceholderTextOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Highlighted">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHighlightedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHighlightedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHighlightedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="FlyoutButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" EnableDependentAnimation="True" From="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownClosedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" To="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPresenterHost">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="6"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="6"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHighlightedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHighlightedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" EnableDependentAnimation="True" From="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" To="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownClosedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPresenterHost">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="6"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Exponent="6"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PresenterStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Full"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InlineNormal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FlyoutButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ShortListOuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InlinePlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FlyoutButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ShortListOuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-4.5" Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" FontWeight="Normal" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemMinHeightThemeSize}" Padding="6.5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Margin="0,0.8,0,0" MinHeight="32.5">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxPlaceholderTextBlockStyle}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Button>
                        <Border x:Name="ShortListOuterBorder" Margin="{ThemeResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <UserControl x:Name="UserControl" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="ItemsPresenterHost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemMinHeightThemeSize}">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceholderTextThemeMargin}" Opacity="0" Style="{StaticResource PlaceholderContentPresenterStyle}"/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Margin="0,0.8,0,0">
                                            <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
                                            </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        </ItemsPresenter>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </UserControl>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In this template (which you can now paste into your page or style resource file where you have your combobox) you will find much more to edit regarding the style, for example you can edit the foreground text color of the closed combobox with more than 5 elements by adding a Foreground attribute to the x:Name="FlyoutButton" Button element.

This article also additionally explains editing the style of a ComboBox:
http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2014/08/23/Breaking-apart-the-Windows-Phone-81-ComboBox-Style-and-Colors.aspx

Comment: Thanks I'll check in morning and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I have thoroughly check that link and provided sample in that link but I couldn't get that how can I change the color of selected item :(

Comment: One more thing, may be that will help you.

Comment: Selected color appears different in different devices according to their selected themes.

Comment: Please, add a screenshot showing which color you want to change - that would help me greatly! But yes, the devices have Light or Dark themes set, and based on that, Colors of the controls may change - so another question - do you want to fix your colors, or acknowledge the selected theme and set colors according to that? The former is easier, and I assume you want that, given you have fixed colors in your sample code.

Comment: Hi, I have added the screen shots. I want to change the green colour in selected item to orange. In my other device it appears red. So I think it is taking colour from theme, which I don't want.

Comment: do you want to fix your colours, Yes I want to fix my colours independent of theme.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So at the article linked above, there is the section "7 requires  a bit more exploration of what happens when the ..." which explains about the "controls:ListPickerFlyoutPresenter" control template ... - have you tried that yet?

Comment: Actually I have tried only section 7, because I also thought that it is what I want but unfortunately I couldn't found the selected state template. I even downloaded the sample and tried that part of application. It changes every colour but not selected item colour :(

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, I cannot change the selected item color either, also tried the sample.

Comment: So, Its not possible ?

Comment: Well, I can't really say it's impossible for certain, because it's just that I have run out of ideas, sorry. I tried fiddling with it again today, but I can't find a way to set the color of the selected item.